# jenkins ssh-agent is not working on specific slave machine

Tags: jenkins, ssh-agent

Suddenly my sshagent step in jenkins pipeline is not working and throwing below error

[image]

But same step with same creds is working fine on master and other slave agents.Also able to see ssh-agent is running on the slave node

```
$ ps -ef|grep -i ssh-agent
root      8548     1  0 11:40 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent -s
root      9622     1  0 12:29 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent -s
```

stage which failing

```
stage('Pull ansible roles') {          
                steps {
                    sshagent(credentials:[XX_XX_KEY_ID]){
                        sh '''
                            ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml -p roles
                        '''
                    }     
                }
            }
```

Could you please guide me what may be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue is with /tmp permission. Jenkins slave user unable to execute ssh-agent command

```
[devops@01 ~]$ ssh-agent
mkdtemp: private socket dir: Permission denied
[devops@01 ~]$ sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
[devops@01 ~]$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-B3lS2R3p2bpT/agent.10399; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=10400; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 10400;
[devops@01 ~]$
```

Reference - https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/815